# Simultaneous WiFi connections

Tags: linux, networking, raspbian, wpa-supplicant, wlan

I've been trying to configure my PI to connect to two networks at the same time with inconsistent results.

I am using both the built in adapter and a USB adapter. The USB adapter reports as a Edimax EW-7811Un (Realtek RTL8188CUS. As for the same file part. When I manually connect the adapters the network settings are both appended to the original supplicant file.

My only success so far has been temporary. If I clear out my wpa-supplicant file and connect each adapter to it's respective network things seem to work fine. This just adds two different entries into the same file for each network though, which I've learned isn't effective as a long term solution. The connection doesn't persist. After some time one network will disassociate and not reconnect and if I restart both adapters will only connect to the first entry in the supplicant file. Any attempt to manually connect the second device to the second network fails and it just stays disassociated. The only workaround seems to be to repeat the process of cleaning the file and manually connecting again.

I found this thread while searching for a solution but I seem to be missing something important:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=190525

I've created the separate supplicant files and entries in the interfaces file as mentioned. However there seems to be a critical step I'm missing as the system keeps referencing the original supplicant file. I assume the op understood some steps in the process that were not explicitly mentioned in the thread, leaving me guessing.

So what am I missing?

Comment: Hello Bolweevil. You're using an external adapter alongside the built-in one? You don't say so explicitly. What device is it (what does `lsusb` report?) What is "_the same file for each network_"? Please be precise [and tell us](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/568080/edit).

Comment: Sorry. Yes I am using both the built in adapter and a USB adapter. The USB adapter reports as a Edimax EW-7811Un (Realtek RTL8188CUS. As for the same file part. When I manually connect the adapters the network settings are both appended to the original supplicant file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from [`man wpa_supplicant`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/wpasupplicant/wpa_supplicant.8.en.html) to control multiple wifi interfaces using multiples configurations files through a single `wpa_supplicant` instance. e,g:

```
wpa_supplicant -iwlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant0.conf -N \
               -iwlan1 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant1.conf
```

To run `wpa_supplicant` in the background, use `-B` option:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -iwlan0 ...
```

sample configuration file:

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant0.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Network0"
    password="pass0"
    }
```

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant1.conf`:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="Network1"
    password="pass1"
    }
```

> ```
>   wpa_supplicant  can  control multiple interfaces (radios) either by running
>     one process for each interface separately or by running just one process and
>     list of options at command line. Each  interface  is separated  with -N 
>     argument. As an example, following command would start wpa_supplicant for two
>     interfaces:
>
>          wpa_supplicant \
>                -c wpa1.conf -i wlan0 -D nl80211 -N \
>                -c wpa2.conf -i ath0 -D wext
> ```

Comment: So I should replace the network connection entries currently in my supplicant file with something similar to that pointing to the separate files I have created with the connection settings? Do I need to specify the driver like in your example or can I rely on the system to detect the driver automatically like it's currently doing?

Comment: @Bolweevil This is just an example. You don't need to specify the driver, also you don't need to rename the wpa_supplicant file.

Comment: Ok. I'm assuming those wpa files are in the same directory as the supplicant file and they contain the network connection settings you might normally find in the supplicant file for a single network setup?

Comment: @Bolweevil For every network interface , set a configuration file , it will be more easy to troubleshot the problem.

Comment: Yes. I had already setup a file for each. I just tried your suggestion. I removed the network settings from my supplicant file and entered the information as you mentioned above. Everything looks the same minus the driver information. When I restarted neither device associated with a network at all. Attempting to click on the network settings icon also reveals that no wireless interfaces are found now.

Comment: @Bolweevil I have update my answer. after setting the configuration run the `wpa_supplicant` from the terminal.

Comment: Thanks for the edit that's much clearer. You may have to be more specific in regards to running that command in the terminal though. Without any modifiers it seems to just bring up the help file.

Comment: Scratch that. Just noticed the edit in the final box. That command does seem to connect the networks correctly. However it only works so long as the terminal is open and running. How would I make this an automatic process on boot?

Comment: @Bolweevil The easy way is to use `cron` , see here https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/.

Comment: So the only way this all works is if I edit all these files to match what's mentioned above and then run that command each time? What purpose do those entries in the main supplicant file serve then?

Comment: @Bolweevil No. It will be executed automatically without the user interaction.

Comment: I understand cron would do that for me but my concern is that I'm basically bypassing the default connection processes by executing a command in this way.  Somehow the person in the thread I linked to got things working via the separate supplicant files and the interfaces file without the use of cron so I was hoping someone here might be able to tell me what I'm missing since whenever I attempt to piece that solution together on my system everything breaks.